# Random 32 hexadecimal digits in Python

Tags: python, hex

I am trying to find a great way to produce a 32 digit hex sequence that is random and gets its randomness from a Big Number like 10*78.

For Python code I also found this:

```
ran = random.randrange(10**80)
myhex = "%030x" % ran
```

This produces a 64 digit hex string, BUT sometimes the result is 63 or even 61 characters and I'm not sure why? I need it to return 64 exactly each time.

I need helping tweaking the above code so that it ALWAYS returns 64 only. I do not know enough about the how the "%030x" part works.

I've also tried producing a longer hex string and shortening it with:

```
myhex = myhex[:64]
```

But I was still seeing strings that were less than 64 being returned.

In the end I just need exactly 64 hexadecimal string derived from a Big Number like 10*78, returned each time.

**Solution I went with**

```
import random

ran = random.randrange(10**80)
myhex = "%064x" % ran

#limit string to 64 characters
myhex = myhex[:64]

print(myhex)
```

Seems @ScottMillers answer below was the key I needed to find the answer so I'm selecting his answer as the solution, but wanted to post my final code that worked for me here.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Its Scott Hunter, not Scott Miller, but I've been called worse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"%030x"` says to display the associated value with *at least* 30 digits, padding with 0's in front as necessary.  Since your numbers are almost always bigger than that, this isn't doing much for you.

It sounds like you need `"%064x"`.

Comment: Thanks. This was key in my final solution so I'm choosing it as my answer.

Answer (score 11):

In modern Python distributions, the new library `secrets` makes it easy and might be what you need. From the docs:

> The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modeling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

For Python 3.6 and up, try this:

```
import secrets
secrets.token_hex(32)
#'17450056b398cbeda1fa7e4fc25d4fb169ade2b1266892e2cecab56b12fb900b'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets

For earlier versions of Python, there is a backport available ([python2-secrets](https://github.com/scaleway/python2-secrets)).

```
   pip install python2-secrets
```

Comment: Note that the number passed to `token_hex` is the number of bytes requested, each corresponding to two hex digits. So to obtain 32 hex digits like the OP wanted, you'd need to use:
`secrets.token_hex(16)`

Answer (score 9):

The UUID module can return a 32 hexadecimal digits object:

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4().hex
# '7dccf8a43a6c4e018caadacdb2d0f6f0'
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that while the result is 128-bit indeed, the values of the 6 most significant bits are defined by the RFC and therefore only 122 bits are random.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such things as "hex numbers"; there's only different representation of the same number (10 in decimal is 0xA in hex and is 0b1010 in binary, but it's still the same number).

> This produces a 64 digit hex string, BUT sometimes the result is 63 or even 61 characters and I'm not sure why? I need it to return 64 exactly each time.

so: I ask you to give me a random number above 0 and below 1000; how many digits will that number have?

Right. It can have one, two or three digits, with three digits being the most likely case (there's 900 three-digit numbers below 1000, but only 90 two digit numbers and 9 one-digit numbers).

Obviously, you just have to pad with 0 in front!

> In the end I just need exactly 64 hexadecimal string derived from a Big Number like 10*78, returned each time.

you need to think about what random means. If you're ok with every single digit being drawn from a uniform distribution in 0..F, then why don't just throw a sixteen-sided die 64 times and concatenate the result? Python makes that extremely easy

```
import random
hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF"
random_digits = "".join([ hexdigits[random.randint(0,0xF)] for _ in range(64) ])
```

**EDIT:**

In the comments below, OP says he wants to use that random string to seed a bitcoin private key generation.

**Never** build your own seeder unless you're really an expert in the field. So, although I believe these 1024 bit (really, that's what a 64 digit of Hex number are) of info are random, I **will not claim this suffices for crypto purposes**.

Don't implement crypto yourself, and don't meddle with seed generation lest you know your ways around stochastics, numerics, cryptography and RNG, computer security research and possible attack vectors. **Simply don't**.

Comment: thanks for clarifying why I was seeing shorter digits sometimes. It starts with a random number duh.  My question now is if rando.randint have enough entropy to support my big number poll requirement? Like up to 10**78. Would you say it does?

Comment: and Marcus your answer does provide a consistent random 64 hex string as required. I have ran it millions of times in testing and always 64.

Comment: @NormanBird unless you start defining what "random" means to you, there's no answer to that, obviously. But probably: The random number generator python uses is pretty good, so chances are that you won't see any patterns in your 1024 bits of randomness.

Comment: notice that defining "random enough" is a hard problem, and there's books and books of math defining what "random" means under different aspects. I really don't know what you need your random digit string for, and you don't seem to be able to articulate that; my "guess" hence that yes, that string is random enough.

Comment: I am attempting generate a script that produces the 32 random hex string needed to generate a Bitcoin private key. My understanding is that the proper entropy needs to come from a pool of at least 10^78 power or a 78 digit random number. That's why you see I start with random.randrange(10**78). I just noticed your solution did not use that part of my original code so I asked.

Comment: **NOOOOPE**. You're going for cryptographically secure. Obviously, this is not your area of expertise. You really should not be doing this. Implementing your own random seed generator is a recipe for disaster. **Never meddle with the generation of cryptographical secrets unless you really know what you're doing**.

Comment: Around three years ago, it was realized that thousands and thousands of computers were easy to crack because someone "improved" a routine in the random generation of openSSH, without knowing **exactly** what he was doing. I wouldn't bet my money on your or my ability to know better!

Comment: That someone **was** an expert in software design. He just wasn't an expert in cryptography and random number generation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108967/discussion-between-norman-bird-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: I get your point. It is not a subtle point you are making. To create a Bitcoin key it is well known that all you require is a random number that can be acquired by simply flipping a coin like 101 times or rolling a dice a certain number of times or even randomly creating a 64 hexadecimal character string. That is all I am trying to do. So please do not misunderstand. People are allowed to flip a coin 101 times and convert that to a key. it happens all the time and is actually one of the best ways to do so.

Comment: @MarcusMueller A Bitcoin private key is not crystallographic in nature. Its just a random number from a large pool of about 10**78. That is all I have ever mentioned I was tying to do.

Comment: For my purpose I believe the range in this answer is too small. He has random.randint(0,0xF) and the randge would have to be more like random.randint(0,0xFFFFFFF). But when I change the answer to that, I get a string index out of range error. So another answer is needed.

Comment: @NormanBird: that comment was total nonsense. Of course, the vector formed by taking 64 random single digits spans the same total number of points as just taking one 64-digit random number. It can't be helped: you'll need to learn about randomness, numbers and such. You really seem to be in over your head.

Comment: @NormanBird: A bitcoin private key seed **is** a cryptographically relevant random number. The fact alone that you don't understand this proves you shouldn't be in charge of generating it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.urandom` instead of hexdump. Python 2.7:

```
import os
num_digits = 32
myhex = os.urandom(num_digits / 2).encode('hex')
```

Py3.4+:

```
import os, codecs
num_digits = 32
myhex = codecs.encode(os.urandom(num_digits / 2), 'hex').decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

For padding zero infront, we can use zfill option.

Ex:
device = '14AB'

> > device.zfill(8)
> >     '000014AB'
> >     device.zfill(64)
> >     '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014AB'

Answer (score 0):

why not just coding something readable for python2 ?

```
import random
value = "%032x" % random.randrange(16**32)
```

( hexadecimal is base 16 )

Answer (score -1):

I would try something like this:

```
mylist = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F]
number = ""

def randomhex():
    global mylist, number
    while len(number) < 32:
        number = number + random.choice(mylist)
```

And if you want it as number, not as string just use eval().

Comment: you can directly use a string (see my answer), which is a sequence type, too, with random.choice.

Comment: But: **never** use `global` without a good reason. Your function is a prime example of where one should use `return` instead. I think you should seriously increase your Python knowledge!

Comment: Well, I'm 15 and have been programming for about a half year and why should I avoid using global variables in functions?

Comment: because that's not how functions are supposed to work: transforming input to output that they `return`. I think it's a great thing to pursue porgamming, so keep up the work!

Comment: Really, though, learn about python functions. I think the official tutorial on python.org explains them in a way that makes the whole input->return thing much more intuitive than the global thing. In general, you should avoid global as much as possible: It is a recipe for disaster, because you might change something on one end of your program that the other end did not foresee.

Comment: `global` is a concept that usually only gets taught in the very end; it's a  "if there's absolutely no way to do this properly, or if you really need global state, use this" concept

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well thanks for your explanation, I'll do my best to avoid globals from now on :D